# Is this a multiple time series problem and suggestions to solve it

Tags: time-series

I'm fairly new to machine learning and especially so to neural network, but I'm assigned to experiment with a machine learning problem and I could really need some help...

What we are doing is we are going to analyze the wear metal elements in lube oil, and basically trying to predict the level of each elements in the future for anomalies detection.

After some research, I assume this is one of the multiple time series problems since elements gradient within lubricating oil could have some inherent connections and therefore, I tried DeepAR but didn't worked quite well. I'm wondering if I am going about it the right way? Or is there any more mature algorithm and model(not necessarily neuron network) I can try out to solve this?(Considering different plant, different types of oil, etc, and DeepAR does support categorical and numeric features)

The second question is, let's say I do end up using DeepAR as my solution, since the factory exchange their oil occationally, Does this mean I need to train the model every time oil gets renewed? Don't want to train the data with the metal elements dropping due to manual exchange of oil. Please provide me with some advices.

To elaborate a bit more
say the first observation is
[image: sencond 0]

And the second observation is
[image: second 1]

Now with DeepAR I would be able to do this
[image]
and hopefully forecast elements level for each sensor?

Big thanks to any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be bringing together several concepts here, and you might want to clarify what your objective is, before going down the path of DeepAR or some other complex Deep Learning model:

- Predicting future oil levels: This is a time series problem only if the main input variables to your model is multiple past values of oil levels, and the target output variable is the same variable in the future (e.g. for sales forecasting we tale the sales number from the last 104 weeks to forecast out the sales for the next 26 weeks). You can have additional inputs (which in this case are called external regressors) but the main input variable has to be the past values of the predicted variable itself, for it to qualify as a time series problem.
- Even if it is a time series problem, you might not need to use a Global model like DeepAR. Often times local Statistical model like ARIMA or a State Space approach are more suited for a time series use case than a deep learning approach. Global Deep Learning or ML based time series models are only suited when you have 100s or 1000s of parallel time series that you want to predict simultaneously, and rich meta-data to connect the different time series together, or when you have a single time series but which is very dense and has a very high signal to noise ratio, like an IoT signal with a very complex pattern that is at a 15 minute granularity, but with data going back several weeks or months.
- Predicting wear and tear in various industrial and manufacturing equipment is typically treated as a mean time to failure problem, not a time series problem. You might want to look into that approach as well.
- You mentioned modeling it as a time series problem for downstream anomaly detection purposes. Not all anomaly detection problems require a dynamic time series signal. Often a static (stationary if you want to get technical) model like K-Means or Isolation Forests is more suitable. The only time your anomaly detection would require a time series based approach, is if the same oil levels can be considered anomalous during sometime of the day or the week, and expected during other times. If a certain set of oil levels is always either anomalous or expected, regardless of the time stamp, then use a static anomaly detection algorithm. Those are much easier to deploy and monitor anyway.

Comment: To address what you've mentioned separately, 1. yes, forecasting future elements level by past elements level is what i am currently trying to do, not sure if it is what i need to do though based on 2 and 3.  2. no, I don't really have much meta data to connect the series actually. So the scenario is, we will use sensors to detect elements like Fe or Cu, sensors in different machines, and perhaps i could train them all together? and put labels on sensors based on the machine condition that varies? ARIMA or State Space approach(some examples please) I would definitely look it up.

Comment: 3 and 4, perhaps i'm wrong to use the term 'anomaly detection', we dont really have a standard of what level of Fe or Cu is too high at the moment. But suppose we have, i want to forecast when it is going to reach that level(at least one element), wether i find a standard or train a different model is another problem. plus, maybe after forecast a time before error, we would intuitively locate the problem(which element level is too high), that's why i would think it's a ts problem. But we do have a 'run time' of the machine, perhaps i could use that as a feature and convert to another problem?

Comment: @Raymow this "i want to forecast when it is going to reach that level" I think is the key sentence then. Time series forecasting model always assume a fixed and predetermined time horizon $T$, and then predict "how much?" will occur at time $T$ or between now and time $T$, they do not forecast "when?". Models that predict "when?" are those that I mentioned before: [Mean time to failure models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures), and their close cousins [Survival analysis models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis).